# Regex capturing IP Address + /subnet format in series of strings and assign each match to a Group

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I have found all the posts that I could find on this site that help to pick out the IP addresses in a given string - and the one that works absolutely best for me I modified it to also grab the /xx subnet info at the end.   For example 192.168.1.1/24

What does NOT work - is that I need each of the IP matches to be put into a group... but every single example I found makes them Non-Capture groups with ?:   and this is useless to me because I cant start grabbing the results to add to a spreadsheet - I'm using Python.

So:

`(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?/\d{1,2})`

run against this string:

```
blah blah  16.13.129.128/25  blah blah 18.83.130.0/24  blah blah  18.18.141.0/24  blah blah 10.17.14.0/24
```

does indeed match each IP :

```
16.13.129.128/25  
18.83.130.0/24  
18.18.141.0/24  
10.17.14.0/24
```

But I cant refer to each IP as Group0, Group1, Group2 etc... for each match.    I don't really understand what ?: is doing (aside from making it a non-capture group) - but when I remove all the ?: thinking they would turn into capture groups - absolutely murders the regex and it doesn't find the IP's anymore.    I've used several regex debug sites to confirm these findings - but I don't know why it completely breaks
when just dropping the ?:

Does anyone know how to get the same regex tweaked to allow for each IP to be assigned to a capture group such as:

```
Group0: 16.13.129.128/25  
Group1: 18.83.130.0/24  
Group2: 18.18.141.0/24  
Group3: 10.17.14.0/24
```

Comment: You're confused about what the term "groups" means in regular expressions. When your regex matches an IP address, and there are multiple IPs in a string, each of those is not a group, it's a *match*. Regex groups have nothing to do with what you want to do, so fiddling with them is pointless. You want to have access to each match, i.e. each IP in your string. So forget about the groups for a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why?  Capture groups name pieces of a single match, so that isn't what you need.
Just use `findall` and put them in a list that you can enumerate or reference by index:

```
import re

ipr = re.compile(r'(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?/\d{1,2})')
s = 'blah blah 16.13.129.128/25 blah blah 18.83.130.0/24 blah blah 18.18.141.0/24 blah blah 10.17.14.0/24'

ips = ipr.findall(s)
for i,ip in enumerate(ips):
    print(f'ips[{i}] = {ip}')
```

Output:

```
ips[0] = 16.13.129.128/25
ips[1] = 18.83.130.0/24
ips[2] = 18.18.141.0/24
ips[3] = 10.17.14.0/24
```